# How can I concat two char pointers into one?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I wanted to know how can I concat two char pointers and if it is even possible? I have a code here;

```
    char* partOne = "1234"; // could have a known N number of bytes
    char* partTwo = "5678"; // could have a known M number of bytes

    char newPart[N+M];
    for(int i= 0; i<N; i++){
       newPart[i++] = *partOne++;
    }
    for(int i = N, j=0; j < M; j++){
       newPart[i++] = *partTwo++;
    }

    std::cout << (char *) newPart << std::endl;
```

Could this be possible to achieve?

Edit:
to be clear on why using char pointers is due to UDP sockets. for example: data I received I have the length of the message in the header

```
while(!closed){
   int bytesReceived = myApi.readData(); // N bytes
   if(bytesReceived <= 0){
       continue;
   }
   char *buffer = myApi.getBuffer(); // returns char * buffer 
   do{
     if(startOf(buffer)){
      //if true check for length of the message
      int messagelen = getMessageLength(buffer);
      while(bytesReeceived < messagelen){
          char * partialBuffer;
          int partialBytesReceived = myApi.readData(); //M bytes
          if(partialBytesReceived <= 0) continue;
          partialBuffer = myApi.getBuffer();
          .....
          //concat two pointers here

         // update N bytesReceived, N += M;
          
      }
    }
  } while(*buffer != '\0');
}
```

In reality I only have access to the updated char * buffer every time I call it. I want to take into account partial messages coming from a UDP socket and bytes received

Comment: You already did? What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: You are missing the terminating '\0'

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The null-termination will probably be incorrect, unless `partOne` is not null-terminated and `partTwo` is. Depends on how `N` and `M` are figured out.

Comment: You cannot "combine" pointers and that is not what you are even attempting. You want to concatenate two strings and you already do that? Of course you can use `memcpy` or `strncpy` instead of writing your own loops. And double of course you can use modern C++ and its `std::vector`,`std::string`, and `<algorithm>` library.

Comment: I'm new to c++, I wanted to see if this was correct or if this is not possible to achieve with pointers in c++

Comment: @Quimby yes I want to concatenate, let me go ahead and rephrase it. sorry!

Comment: @Recursive It's possible provided `N` and `M` are *compile time constants*, you just described them as 'known' so this is not clear. Perhaps you should elaborate on that. Apart from that you have the error of not having a null terminator as pointed out above.

Comment: Are the buffers storing strings ending with "\0", or is their length only known from `N` and `M`? For strings, look at the C `strcat` solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432638/how-can-i-combine-two-pointers-into-one

Comment: @recursive I already explained to you that in context of UDP datagrams, which may contain `0` bytes, your approach cannot work. You're barking up at the wrong tree here. If you're looking for reliable c++ solutions receiving UDP datagrams, have a look af `boost::asio`.

Comment: @Recursive I have to ask -- why this convoluted code to concatenate two string literals?  Of course C++ can concatenate strings, but this looks [Rube Goldberg-ish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) to me.

Comment: @deribaucourt — C-style strings end with the **character** `'\0'`, not with the **string** `”\0”` (which is two characters).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that is taken into account already with in an if loop, sorry for not pointing out last time

Comment: @Recursive wth is an _if loop_?? `if` provides branches in code,  not _"loops"_. As mentioned, concatenation that way isn't your primary problem. Have a thorough look at the data you received in the buffer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I edited my question, hopefully that makes sense now

Comment: If your `rvcfrom()` is passed the location to store into, then you should be using that to ensure that new data goes immediately after the partial results in your buffer, instead of moving it after the fact.

Comment: @Recursive well, it confirms my assumptions. Where are you making sure, that the received data doesn't (intentionally) contains zero byte values (`0`). `concat()` cannot work with such.

Comment: @recursive Notable: You should disclose the binary structure you want to receive as UDP datagrams along your question. There's no general solution to do that properly.

Comment: @TobySpeight okay, I am a little confuse, sorry, I'm new to udp sockets and networking. When receiving partial message means that there was not enough space to store the data and you should receive the rest in another message or for some reason the message was sent in two parts? If so could I be receiving part of the message and a new message with it together?

Comment: You've changed the code since I wrote that, and now `myApi.readData()` makes its own choice where to put the received data.  If you can't change that, you're stuck with copying.  I'd call that a poor design of the `myApi` object.

Comment: @TobySpeight I can modify existing myApi, just that it has been there, but how could I improve that, to do what you just said from the *rcvfrom()* part

Comment: Why are you complicating your life by using pointers when you could just use `std::string` objects?

Comment: @JesperJuhl how can you convert a char * buffer with NBytes into a string where buffer could have (*0*) or 0x00 in it? or how can you convert it into a std::vector<char>?

Comment: The constructor `std::string::string(const char*,std::size_t)` has no problems with null characters.  Why do you think it would?

Comment: @TobySpeight sorry I just got it confused and was not familiar with c++, after all I followed you guys advice and decided to go for a vector of uint8_t. I just got it confused because in a tutorial I saw you put '\0' null character to specify the end of the string when printing out. Therefore I thought it would cause any type of issues.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you! I was having issues trying to convince some people to re engineer the whole program, but we did and it was much simpler by A LOT. I just wanted to return to thank you for that. Hopefully we meet again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using C-style strings (character arrays), you could join them by using `strcpy` and `strcat`.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    char* partOne = "1234"; // could have a known N number of bytes
    char* partTwo = "5678"; // could have a known M number of bytes

    // In reality you'd want to use `strlen` and allocate on the heap
    // for this, so that you can deal with any size of buffer
    char newPart[N+M+1];
    // Copy the first string in
    std::strcpy(newPart, partOne);
    // Then add (concatenate) the second string to the end
    std::strcat(newPart, partTwo);

    std::cout << newPart << '\n';
}
```

However, you should keep in mind that using C-style strings in C++ code is often a bad idea. It would be safer to create `std::string` objects from the buffers, and join them using the `+` operator. Doing so would have less risk of buffer overruns and other bugs.

Comment: It was my downvote! I'd honestly forgotten. OK it's removed.

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge Thank you for making me realize that is bad idea to use C-Style in a C++ program. I ended up using `std::vector<char>` due to my later algorithms I needed to run over my data. Thanks again I will display this as my answer since I did ask for concatenation on two c style strings.

Answer (score 3):

The right way is the simple:

```cpp
int main(){

    std::string partOne = "1234";
    std::string partTwo = "5678";

    std::string newPart = partOne + partTwo;

    std::cout << newPart << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: This appears to use `std::string` when OP wants to use `char*`

Comment: I wanted to write a similar answer, although it is not directly what OP wants, it is what OP very likely *wants*.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want to *avoid* string concatenation.  (You could do that by constructing a `std::string` and a `std::string_view`, using start pointer and length for each, then using `+` operator, but that's pointless copying).

Instead, arrange for the subsequent read to *append* to the data you already have.

The standard pattern for this goes something like:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
char *p = buffer;
std::size_t len = sizeof buffer;
while (/*need more data*/) {
    auto bytes_read = read(input_fd, buf, len);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
        /* error handling here */
        return FAILURE_CODE;
    }
    p += bytes_read;
    len -= bytes_read;
}
```

We then have `p-buffer` bytes stored stored contiguously beginning at `buffer`.

Comment: Does this takes into account possible partialMessage from a *recvfrom()*

Comment: If the function correctly returns the number of bytes received, yes (i.e. if it behaves like [the POSIX `read()` function](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html)).

Comment: `recvfrom()` on a UDP socket can't return partial messages. It returns the whole message, or the message is discarded if the receiving buffer is too small. There is no in between, like there is with a TCP socket.

Comment: That's true @Remy - but I'm not sure whether the OP's function call is directly wrapping `recvfrom()` or something bigger (like assembling data from multiple UDP packets).  Though now I think about it, the latter would seem strange, given the lack of guarantee on order of delivery.