# How do you return a char * from two char pointer? Error when returning local pointer. What could be the best procedures to deal with RAW data buffer

Tags: c++, function

Lets say I have a prepend function:

```
//for example xMessage = "apple";
//for example yMessage = "juice";
//answer should be newMessage = "applejuice"

char* concat(char *xMessage, int xSize, char* yMessage, int ySize){
     char newMessage[xSize+ySize];
     for(....){
        //copyxMessage
     }
     for(....){
        //copyYMessage
     }
    return (char *) newMessage;
}
```

I know I can use strings, but would preferably keep them as an array of bytes. What could be the best solution for this to avoid the error of returning a local pointer.

SOLUTION: Create a vector or deque of uint8_t depending on the needs of the type of manipulation/algorithms of RAW data. I ended up using a std::vector<uint8_t>. Ex.

`std::vector<uint8_t> data(buffer + bytesIn);`

Due to in my case receiving data from a socket.

Edit: After reading the replies, the most convenient solution was to create a vector of chars or a string. Since I had a bunch of bytes being sent I decided to go with a `std::vector<uint8_t>` due to more manipulation I had to do later in the program. Thank you everyone for making me realize that and helping me with this. The reason I was messing with raw char pointers is because the data I was dealing with was RAW data, but converting it into a vector it was easier to manipulate the data, than dealing with char pointers.

Comment: This is C++. Why mess around with raw `char*` when `std::string` is right there. Combined with `std::tuple` you have a solution here. This function isn't even needed if you did the stuff with `std::string`, as you can just do `x + y`.

Comment: Use `std::string`. Don’t mess with C-style stfings.

Comment: `char newMessage[xSize+ySize];` -- This is not valid C++ code anyway.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by compile-time values, not runtime values.

Comment: Sorry, but you need [a good C++ book](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vbYlqgWZk8) to learn from. You can't learn C++ by asking questions on SO the whole day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [const char\* concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995053/const-char-concatenation)

Comment: *I know I can use strings, but I can't do it for this issue.* -- I am going to make a friendly wager of a cup of coffee that what you are saying isn't really true.   I bet you don't know *how* to use `std::string` properly enough to not have to use char arrays like this.

Comment: It's great that you're asking questions, but please, **SLOW DOWN AND [READ THE ANSWERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432638/how-can-i-concat-two-char-pointers-into-one)** to your previous questions. It's extremely disrespectful to just blunder along and make the same mistakes. It's also a huge waste of your time as well as everyone else's.

Comment: Also, you are returning the address of a local variable, even if that local variable is a fake C++ array.  That is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could be a "C++" professor who has no idea what C++ actually is, and is irrationally terrified of anything in `std`.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? [How can I concat two char pointers into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432638/how-can-i-concat-two-char-pointers-into-one)

Comment: @tadman this is due to an error, not because I did not read previous answers. I had to work around and now I did it, but get an error as stated in my question. Kinda different issue.

Comment: @tadman Something that has been part of standard C++ for 25 years now, you would think that the idiotic "you can't use std::string" was done away with in this day and age.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You'd think, and yet here we are. I mean it's hard to teach C++ even from 25 years ago when you're inflicting a 30 year old compiler like Turbo C++ on your unfortunate students.

Comment: A) You can't (reliably) use VLAs (Variable Length Arrays, like `char x[n]`) in C++. B) You will need to `new[n]` instead. C) Because of that, now you've inherited a whole world of hurt to do with *memory management*. D) You really should use `std::string`, and even if you can't because *reasons*, keep that in mind. E) **DO NOT** forget the **NUL terminator** part of the allocation, it's always "length + 1". F) **DO NOT** forget to **NUL terminate**, the last byte of that must be 0.

Comment: So in summary: C++ `return a + b`. C shaped C++: `new[]`, `strcpy`, `strcat`, and a whole other mess of responsibilities.

Comment: `char* concat(char *xMessage, int xSize, char* yMessage, int ySize)` -- That declaration in C++ code raises more questions than you realize.  1) Where does the returned `char *` come from?  Is it dynamically allocated? If so, was it created with `new[]`? or `malloc`?  What if `xSize` and/or `ySize` are the incorrect values and now you have a buffer overrun, one of the errors where code can be exploited.  See what teaching `C` in a C++ course gives you?

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you I just noticed. Looks like I was making sure to edit my questions to make sure why I needed to use char pointers. I accepted the answer since that was my mistake. I kept getting hate for trying to learn more about pointers. Also, looks like they made me realize of a better way to do this since I was getting confused with probable issues of having null values inside my data I was receiving. Thank you for making me notice that. Sorry about that

Comment: @Recursive You're welcome and hang in there!

Comment: @Recursive _"How do you return a char * from two char pointer?"_  / _"I know I can use strings, but would preferably keep them as an array of bytes"_ - I thought the question was clear, but apparently, there was more to it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use std::string

```
std::string concat(char *xMessage, int xSize, char* yMessage, int ySize){
  std::string s(xMessage);
  s += yMessage;
  return s;
}
```

If you really want a pointer to the appended string buffer you can use a wrapper around `concat`.

Comment: Better would be to take in `std::string` objects as input, eg: `std::string concat(const std::string &xMessage, const std::string &yMessage){ return xMessage + yMessage; }`.  You can still pass in `char*` strings to them, if needed. But really, you can just eliminate this function altogether if you just use `std::string` as-is, eg: `std::string xMessage = "apple"; std::string yMessage = "juice"; std::string newMessage = xMessage + yMessage;`

Comment: Alternatively take `std::string_view`s which could be cheaper to construct, if there are already char arrays containing the data. Even if `std::string`s are used, they can be converted to `std::string_view`s. Btw: you may want to construct an empty string first, then reserve followed by 2 calls to `append` to avoid the possibility of a reallocation of the string memory. `std::string s; s.reserve(xSize + ySize); s.append(xMessage, xSize); s.append(yMessage, ySize); return s;`

Comment: While I agree that using std::string for parameter is better, taking a std::string may not be a choice for OP.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I absolutely do not agree with doing this, but since you know you can use a `std::string` but would like to do it with raw pointers, here's one way:

- Allocate a buffer large enough to hold `xSize + ySize` characters + 1 extra for the terminating `\0`. You do this with `new[]`.
- `std::memcpy` the input strings into the allocated buffer.
- Don't forget to `delete[]` the buffer after use.

```cpp
#include <cstring>

char* concat(const char *xMessage, int xSize, const char* yMessage, int ySize) {
    char* newMessage = new char[xSize + ySize + 1];

    std::memcpy(newMessage, xMessage, xSize);
    std::memcpy(newMessage + xSize, yMessage, ySize);
    newMessage[xSize + ySize] = '\0';

    return newMessage;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hbvzes5xq)

Comment: Thanks it worked and I will make sure to delete[] the buffer answer!

Comment: @Recursive This will all fall apart if `concat` is called where the return value is temporary.  You won't get a chance to `delete` the buffer, since the buffer pointer returned would have disappeared.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it'll leak if the returned pointer is not `delete[]`d for sure.

Comment: You can use `unique_ptr` even with dynamic-sized arrays to handle that issue.

Comment: @DanielH Absolutely - or better, return a `std::string` and take `std::string_view`s as input.

Comment: And this is how the bugs get created in a C++ code. Using `new` is definitely not a good idea where there is no control of lifetime. `unique_ptr` is better or maybe create an object which saves the allocated char buffer.

Comment: @A.K. The better option would be to use `std::string`

Answer (score 0):

The function declaration

```
char* concat(char *xMessage, int xSize, char* yMessage, int ySize){
```

does not make sense.

Firstly, if the arrays pointed to by the pointers `xMessage` and `yMessage` are not changed within the function then the corresponding parameters should be declared with qualifier `const`.

Or if characters from the array pointed to by the parameter `yMessage` are appended to the array pointed to by the pointer `xMessage` then in any case the parameter `yMessage` should be declared with qualifier `const`.

Secondly, if the parameters `xMessage` and `yMessage` point to strings and you need to build a new string that will contain concatenated strings then parameters `xSize` and `ySize` are senseless.

If you indeed need to build a string that will contain concatenated passed strings then the function can look the following way

```
char * concat( const char *xMessage, const char *yMessage )
{
    size_t xLen = strlen( xMessage );

    char *result = new char[ xLen + strlen( yMessage ) + 1 ];

    memcpy( result, xMessage, xLen );
    strcpy( result + xLen, yMessage );

    return result;
}
```

And the function can be called for example like

```
char *result = concat( "apple", "juice" );
```

The caller of the function is responsible for deleting the concatenated string when it will not be required any more like

```
delete [] result;
```